# Run an magento function cron at every hour

Tags: magento, cron, magento-1.7

I  want to  run an magento function that would run at every hour , i am written code in config.xml but i did not working.here the code is

```
<crontab>
            <jobs>
                <stockalert_autosend>
                <schedule><cron_expr>**/1 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>stockalert/observer::backinstock</model></run>
            </stockalert_autosend>
            </jobs>
        </crontab>
```

Please help me

Comment: is it calling your custom function ?

Comment: yes.i  am creating a custom module

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this cron expression for each hour:

```
<cron_expr>0 * * * *</cron_expr>
```

This will make it run at `12.00`, `1.00` and so on.
If you want to make it run at `12.30`, `1.30` and so on replace `0` with `30`

Comment: Please I wants to run Daily 1 am. can you comment answer?

Comment: @KetanKpBorada: `0 1 * * *`