# How to get Magento cronjob to run once a day

Tags: magento, cron

I am trying to run a cronjob in Magento once a day but it is not working.

This is the syntax I am using:

```
<cron_expr>0 21 * * * *</cron_expr>
```

If I have the cronojob run every five minutes to 120 minutes it works fine:

```
<cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr>
```

Here's some other ways I have tried to get the cronjob to run once a day:

```
<cron_expr>*/1440 * * * *</cron_expr>
<cron_expr>*/5 1 * * *</cron_expr>
<cron_expr>*/0 1 * * *</cron_expr>
<cron_expr>*/* 1 * * * *</cron_expr>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
<cron_expr>* 0 * * *</cron_expr>
```

oR

```
<cron_expr>0 0 * * *</cron_expr>
```

Check

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21374844/run-an-magento-function-cron-at-every-hour
```